# Comparar URL com PHP

Tags: php

Quero fazer um `if` para comparar URLs, tentei usando `parse_url`... mas não sei bem como usá-lo. Alguém poderia me dar uma ajudinha?

```
<?php 
    $url1 = parse_url ( "http://enquetegoias.esy.es" ); 
    $url2 = parse_url ( "http://enquetegoias.esy.es/pesquisa.html" );
?>
<?php if ($url1['host']  == $url2['host'] ): ?>

        <meta property="og:image" content="http://enquetegoias.esy.es/img/logo.jpg" />

        <meta itemprop="image" content="http://enquetegoias.esy.es/img/logo.jpg" />

    <?php else: ?>

        <meta property="og:image" content="http://enquetegoias.esy.es/img/votacao.jpg" />

        <meta itemprop="image" content="<?=URL?>img/layout/votacao.jpg" />

    <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Você quer comparar para obter que resultado ?

Comment: Se url1 iguall a http://enquetegoias.esy.es{
<meta property="og:image" content="http://enquetegoias.esy.es/img/logo.jpg" />

        <meta itemprop="image" content="http://enquetegoias.esy.es/img/logo.jpg" />} senão{
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://enquetegoias.esy.es/img/votacao.jpg" />

        <meta itemprop="image" content="<?=URL?>img/layout/votacao.jpg" />}

Comment: Tente esclarecer um pouco mais sua questão. Qual o resultado esperado? A verificação está correta.

Comment: Por exemplo, se a página que o usuário se encontrar for http://enquetegoias.esy.es então quero que apareça:
<meta property="og:image" content="http://enquetegoias.esy.es/img/logo.jpg" />

        <meta itemprop="image" content="http://enquetegoias.esy.es/img/logo.jpg" />

mas se o usurário se encontrar em http://enquetegoias.esy.es/pesquisa.html quero que apareça:
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://enquetegoias.esy.es/img/votacao.jpg" />

        <meta itemprop="image" content="<?=URL?>img/layout/votacao.jpg" />

Comment: Conseguiu fazer? @FernandaFerreira

Comment: Não consegui, não rs

Comment: conseguiu desenvolver?

Comment: Ainda não (parei de mexer). Você está com a mesma dificuldade?

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp( string $str1, string $str2 )`

Recebe duas strings como parâmetro. Retorna < 0 se a $str1 for menor que $str. Retorna > 0 se $str1 for maior que a $str2 e finalmente, retorna 0, se as duas strings forem iguais.

`strcasecmp( string $str1, string $str2 )`

Idêntica a função strcmp(), com a diferença que a strcmp() diferencia maiúsculas e minúsculas, e a função strcasecmp() não diferencia maiúsculas e minúsculas.